# Why is it blowing past the first one?

Tags: php, foreach, require-once

I build a function that if you give it an array of paths it will look for a file in each path and if you give it an array of one path it will look in that path only for the file.

My questions, is when you give it an array of paths such as:

```
$array = array(
    'template_view_paths' => array(
        'path_name' => some/path/
        'path_name_two' => some/path/two/
    )
)
```

It seems to find the file in `some/path/` but keeps going on to `some/path/two/` and freaks out because the file doesn't exist. What would I have to change so that if it find the file in  any path that it stops looking in other paths?

**The code - NOT re-factored**

```
public function render_view($template_name){
    if(!isset($this->_options['template_view_path'])){
        throw new AisisCore_Template_TemplateException('Not view path was set.');
    }

    if(is_array($this->_options['template_view_path'])){
        foreach($this->_options['template_view_path'] as $template=>$path){
            require_once($path . $template_name . '.phtml');
        }
    }else{
        if(!file_exists($this->_options['template_view_path'] . $template_name . '.phtml')){
            throw new AisisCore_Template_TemplateException('Could not find: ' . $template_name . '.phtml at ' . $path);
        }

        require_once ($this->_options['template_view_path'] . $template_name . '.phtml');
    }
}
```

**Note:** *the part to focus on is the `if(is_array()){}` loop*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't:

```
if(is_array($this->_options['template_view_path'])){
    foreach($templates as $template=>$path){
        require_once($path . $template_name . '.phtml');
    }
}else{
```

be:

```
if(is_array($this->_options['template_view_path'])){
    foreach($this->_options['template_view_path'] as $template=>$path){
        if (file_exists($filename = $path . $template_name . '.phtml')) {
            require_once($filename);
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new AisisCore_Template_TemplateException('Could not find: ' . $template_name . '.phtml in any paths');
}else{
```

You're never actually looping `$this->_options['template_view_path']`.

Comment: Your right I made a small mistake. Which I have fixed. I also see what you did by checking for it. Although your check is messy. But it works, and will be cleaned up. Thank you